# How do I inject a packet inside of pcap_loop's callback function?

Tags: c, sockets, libpcap

I am completely new to *sockets programming*. I am trying to sniff and spoof packets. I am `using pcap_loop` in the `libpcap` library in *Linux* with this signature:

```
int pcap_loop(pcap_t *p, int cnt, pcap_handler callback, u_char *user);
```

and I wanted to use `pcap_inject` or `pcap_sendpacket` to inject a packet from within the callback function inside of `pcap_loop`.

However, `pcap_inject` and `pcap_sendpacket` require the `pcap_t *` handle to send the **raw packet**.

It seems like the callback function doesn't have an easy way to access the handle. I was wondering if it's at all possible to access it from within the callback, or if there is an easier way to be doing this.

Answer (score 1):

That's what the `user` argument to the callback is for.  I'm not sure why it's a `u_char *` rather than a `void *`, given that it's a "generic pointer", and given that BPF dates back to 1992, by which time I think *most* C compilers supported `void *` - maybe not all did.

In any case, a pointer to an arbitrary value can be passed to the callback by passing it as an argument to `pcap_loop()` or `pcap_dispatch()`; that could be a pointer to a structure containing, among other values, the `pcap_t *` from which you're capturing.

That way, the callback can call `pcap_inject()`, using that `pcap_t *`.